# Make date column into standard format using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How can I use pandas to make dates column into a standard format i.e. 12-08-1996. The data I have is:

[image]

I've tried some methods by searching online but haven't found the one where it detects the format and make it standard.

Here is what I've coded:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'date cleanup.xlsx')
df.head(10)
df.DOB = pd.to_datetime(df.DOB) #Error is in this line
```

The error I get is:

> ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '20\ \december\ \1992')

**UPDATE:**
Using

```
for date in df.DOB:
    print(parser.parse(date))
```

Works great but there is a value 20\\december \\1992 for which it gives the above highlighted error. So I'm not familiar with all the formats that are in the data this is why I was looking for a technique that can auto-detect it and convert it to standard format.

Comment: `from dateutil import parser` , `parser.parse('17th Jun')` gives `datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 17, 0, 0)` , if it doesnt work , please provide code to create df

Comment: @anky_91 this works great but there are some strings like `20\\december\\1992` where the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`dateparser`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library:

```
import dateparser

df = pd.DataFrame(["12 aug 1996", "24th december 2006", "20\\ december \\2007"], columns = ['DOB'])
df['date'] = df['DOB'].apply(lambda x :dateparser.parse(x))
```

**Output**

```
|   |        DOB         |    date    |
|---|--------------------|------------|
| 0 | 12 aug 1996        | 1996-08-12 |
| 1 | 24th december 2006 | 2006-12-24 |
| 2 | 20\ december \2007 | 2020-12-07 |
```

**EDIT**

Note, there is a [`STRICT_PARSING`](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#incomplete-dates) setting which can be used to handle exceptions :

> You can also ignore parsing incomplete dates altogether by setting STRICT_PARSING

```
df['date'] = df['DOB'].apply(lambda x : dateparser.parse(x, settings={'STRICT_PARSING': True}) if len(str(x))>6 else None)
```

Comment: I got an error: `TypeError: Input type must be str or unicode`

Comment: what does `df.dtypes` give?

Comment: try `pd.read_excel(r'date cleanup.xlsx', converters={'DOB':str})` when importing the excel file

Comment: `df.dtypes` shows that the type of DOB is `DOB  object` and typing `pd.read_excel(r'date cleanup.xlsx', converters={'DOB':str})` gave the same error.

Comment: and replacing `dateparser.parse(x)` by `dateparser.parse(str(x))` ? Something is wrong in the format of `DOB` but can't figure what without the file

Comment: This works :) actually the data is in very bad shape some date values are like *Ist January*, *00.00.1958*, *26 101996*, *20dece1999* and for some there is only year so by default it is picking *06 month and 17 day* so I guess I have to fix them manually. Is there a way I can just add **ERROR** where there is an exception? If yes then what modification will you make to the answer you've suggested?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195069/discussion-between-sebastien-d-and-chaudhry-talha).

Comment: This helps with some exceptions, but there are some value where there is only year given and it is picking up day and month automatically and there is a cell which is blank in DOB but still it's picking up today's date.